# Ajax post request return 400 Bad request (Maven server on localhost + mysql database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, maven

I'm trying to send ajax post request (jQuery) and I am having 400 bad request error. But complete returns me in responseText a string with correct data. In postman everything works fine. I am using maven for server and mysql database. I try everyhing what I have found on the internet but nothing works for me. (Sorry for my poor english)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not http://localhost:8080/book/genres?callback=getGenre&jsonBook=%7B%22genre%22%3A%22drama%22%7D&_=1519810685433 Allowed)

maven:

```
public List<String> getGenre(Genre genre){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        String query = "select name from books inner join books_details on 
                        books.id = books_details.id where genre LIKE ?";;

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1,genre.getGenre());
        System.out.println(genre);
        System.out.println(query);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String name=rs.getString("name");
            list.add(name);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;

@POST
@Path("/genres")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String getGenres(Genre genre){
    System.out.println(genre);
    List<String>list= new MySQL().getGenre(genre);
    System.out.println(list);
    boolean b= false;
    String result= "({\"getGenre\":[";
    for(String temp:list){
        if(b==true){
            result+=',';
        }
        else
            b=true;
        result+="\""+temp+"\"";
    }
    result+="]})";

    return result;
}

$(".thisBook").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var bookId = ((this).id);
    var book = {
        genre: bookId
    };

    var jsonBook = JSON.stringify(book);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/book/genres',
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonBook  ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: getGenre,
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: getGenre
    });

    function getGenre(data){
        console.log(data.responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

Comment: please post exact whole error message.

Comment: If you're receiving a 400 issue then the issue is on the server and you need to diagnose it. Generally speaking it's caused by sending invalid data (or having missing data) in the request

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not http://localhost:8080/book/genres?callback=getGenre&jsonBook=%7B%22genre%22%3A%22drama%22%7D&_=1519810685433 Allowed)

Comment: But why I get data to complete if there is issue on server side?

Comment: when i call a function in complete I get in response text ({"getGenre":["Hamlet","The Great Gatsby","The Book Thief","The Alchemist","One Hundred Years of Solitude"]}) a that is what I am looking for

Comment: The 'Method not allowed' error means that the server does not accept a POST request to this endpoint. Check your code to ensure you've configured it correctly, and that it's not expecting a GET or PUT for example

Comment: It'is a kind of routing problem: Do that route book/genres exist in your server?

Comment: I checked it and yes, the route is correct

Comment: I edited an answer and I added also maven